# Could not resolve reference to dll from nuget package

Tags: tfs, msbuild, nuget

On my TFS build, nuget packages download and unzip ok during a pre-build script.
The during the build references for dlls coming from nuget are not being resolved:
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "<asesembly_name>"`

I have not checked in the nuget /packages into TFS source control - I don't think you are supposed to do that.

Unresolved reference example:

```
<Reference Include="Gestion_Excepciones"> 
 <HintPath>..\..\..\..\packages\Gestion_Excepciones.1.0.0.0\lib\net35\Gestion_Excepciones.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Build log (sorry, in Spanish)

> Referencia principal "Gestion_Excepciones". (TaskId:10) 17:22:37.274
>   2>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5):
>   warning MSB3245: No se pudo resolver esta referencia. No se encuentra
>   el ensamblado "Gestion_Excepciones". Compruebe si el ensamblado existe
>   en el disco. Si el código necesita esta referencia, podrían producirse
>   errores de compilación.
>   [C:\Builds\1\Egestiona\eLegisla\src\source\website\modules\eLegisla\asp.net_eLegisla.BussinesLayer.Datos\asp.net_eLegisla.BussinesLayer.Datos.csproj]
>   **> Para SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}". (TaskId:10) Se consideró
>   "..\..\..\..\packages\Gestion_Excepciones.1.0.0.0\lib\net35\Gestion_Excepciones.dll",
>   pero no existía.** (TaskId:10) Para SearchPath
>   "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}". (TaskId:10) Se consideró "C:\Program
>   Files\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\Gestion_Excepciones.winmd", pero
>   no existía. (TaskId:10) Se consideró "C:\Program Files\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\Gestion_Excepciones.dll", pero no
>   existía. (TaskId:10) Se consideró "C:\Program Files\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\Gestion_Excepciones.exe", pero no
>   existía. (TaskId:10) ...

English version via Bing Translator

> Main reference " Management _ exceptions ". (TaskId:10) 17:22:37.274
>   2>`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5)`: warning MSB3245: 
> This reference could not be resolved. The Assembly is not found "Exceptions_management". Check if the Assembly exists on disk. If the code needs this reference, could lead to compilation errors. `[C:\Builds\1\Egestiona\eLegisla\src\source\website\modules\eLegisla\asp.net_eLegisla.BussinesLayer.Datos\asp.net_eLegisla.BussinesLayer.Datos.csproj]` 
> > For SearchPath "`{HintPathFromItem}`". 
> (TaskId:10) It was considered "`..\..\..\..\packages\Exceptions_management.1.0.0.0\lib\net35\Exceptions_management.dll`", but there was no. 
> (TaskId:10) For SearchPath "`{TargetFrameworkDirectory}`". 
> (TaskId:10) It was considered "`C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\Exceptions_management.winmd`", but there was no. 
> (TaskId:10) It was considered "`C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\Exceptions_management.dll`", but there was no. 
> (TaskId:10) It was considered "`C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\Exceptions_management.exe`", but there was no. 
> (TaskId:10) ...

The build log shows msbuild considered the HintPath and was unable to find it - but I can see it's there! Isn't HintPath relative to the .csproj directory?

I am using

MSBuildBinPath = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

nuget 2.8.1

TFS 2012

Comment: Is the library that has the nuget reference used in multiple solutions? It maybe the case that the hint path for the solution in which you added the nuget reference is not applicable in the solution you are building.

Comment: All projects on all solutions use the same packages directory, the difference obviously being the number of ..\ blocks the hintpaths use to point to the dlls. Not sure this is the issue, as all projects compile ok on visual studio, on the developers boxes. To be specific, nuget is using a nuget.config that is common to all solutions ($project/main/source/nuget.config), which in turn specifies a common packages directory ($project/main/source/packages)

Comment: Try a build with the Verbosity set to "Diagnostic", and have a look through the output, that's my usual tactic.

Comment: So is mine, just double-checked, it's on diagnostic mode. No additional info regarding the dll ref, other than the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checked in /packages on TFS 2013 source control, now the references are being resolved. This leaves me somewhat frustrated - afaik one of nuget raisons d'être is you don't have to check in packages (read dlls,) because they live on their package repository.